# Flatten transformation for the json-string column (data flow in ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I copy a csv file with a json-string column to the data flow.

[image]
I want to flatten it by the json-string column, but the column is not recognized as a json format.

How do I convert it to json-format column, or do you have other ways to deal with it? Thank you

Comment: Hi @Qianru Song, JSON value contains {"key":"value"}. It seems that column named "Data" does not look to be in JSON format.

Comment: Hi Joseph, yes that is not json. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ref my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65770042/10549281

If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know.

HTH.