# Split a json string column or flatten transformation in data flow (ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I copy the following csv file to a data flow in ADF.

[image]

The column Data has json format, but it is considered string. I want to flatten Data column into individual rows. I tried the flatten transformation, it did not work as Data column is not json. How do I deal with it? I also tried split expression, and it did not work either. Thank you

Comment: The column named "Data" does not look to be in JSON format , right ?

Comment: It looks like json format, but when I copy it from csv dataset it becomes string format. In the excel csv, it has json format. If it is in its json format in the data flow, I can flatten the column. In the source projection, there is no options to change string for json. How can I handle with it? Thank you

Comment: @QianruSong Just from your screenshot, data is not in JSON format. You source is an excel file. Can you show us the data look like in the excel file? Source can not convert  the column data type  to josn. But in data flow, we can use derived column expressions to flatten it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from your screenshot, We can find that :

1. The data in `Data` are not JSON format.
2. Data most look like an Array.
3. The 'array' has 9 elements.

Me must consider it as the "Array" then we could using Data Flow [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to flatten the Data. Please ref my steps bellow:

**Source data:**
[image]

**Derived Column expressions and settings:**

The expression to make data as string and using index to get the value:

```
Data 1: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[1]
Data 2: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[2]
Data 3: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[3]
Data 4: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[4]
Data 5: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[5]
Data 6: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[6]
Data 7: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[7]
Data 8: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[8]
Data 9: split(substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2), ",")[9]
```

[image]

**Derived Column output:**
[image]

If the `Data` are standard JSON format, we need convert the string to JSON first, and then use the key to get the value.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Leon, I thought it was json, because I used the function - parse json to extract numbers in the dataflow of powerBI. Your answer is very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hi Leon, I have the situation you described, a column that has an entire JSON string in it, I need to parse it and load the data into SQL database. 
I don't think that there's an expression that can do that in a derived column (at least I wasn't able to find one), did you experience this before, how did you convert the string to JSON?

Comment: @quickshare can you post a new question with more details?

Comment: ok, I've added more details and posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437383/use-azure-data-factory-to-parse-json-string-from-a-column 
thanks for taking a look into it